# Update ListAdapter Dynamically During execution

Tags: android

I am trying to change the ListView data mid-program by using a button at the top that switches between negative and positive lists.

```
private ArrayList<LifeTask> positiveListData = new ArrayList<LifeTask>();
private ArrayList<LifeTask> negativeListData = new ArrayList<LifeTask>();
private ArrayList<LifeTask> currentListData = positiveListData;
private ListAdapter adapter;
private ListView gameList;
```

By default I have `currentListData` pointing to the positive list.  In the `onCreate()` function of the app I have the following code:

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, currentListData);
gameList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list_view);
gameList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When the negative button is pressed I try doing the following:

```
currentListData = negativeListData;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but nothing changes.  What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: Adapter code added as per requested

```
package cs.ucsb.cs185.dimberman.lifeRPG;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LifeTask>{
    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    ArrayList<LifeTask> data = null;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<LifeTask> List_Data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, List_Data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = List_Data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ItemHolder holder = null;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ItemHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.ItemName);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ItemHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        LifeTask s = data.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(s.getName());
        return row;

    }

    static class ItemHolder{

        TextView name;

    }
}
```

Comment: @ZainAli no luck.  It didn't update the list being shown at all.

Comment: Could You share adapter code?

Comment: @MasterGberry : Get rid of `ArrayList<LifeTask> data = null;` and `this.data = List_Data;` and change `LifeTask s = data.get(position);` to be `LifeTask s = (LifeTask) getItem(position);`. The reason is, doing it your way, `data` will always reference the first `ArrayList<LifeTask>` that is passed to the constructor of `ListAdapter` regardless of how you change the reference for `currentListData` in your main code.

Comment: You are changing the **currentListData** to a new list, but the adapter is still using the old list. You should either set a new adapter or simply clear the adapter list (in that case you always use the methods **add** or **addAll** to assign the list items, in case you are using an **ArrayAdapter**, because using the method **clear** will also the clear the list that you assigned to the adapter during initialization).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to change Your adapter the following way:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LifeTask> {
    int layoutResourceId;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<LifeTask> List_Data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, List_Data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ItemHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = parent.getContext().getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ItemHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.ItemName);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ItemHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        final LifeTask s = getItem(position);
        holder.name.setText(s.getName());
        return row;
    }

    static class ItemHolder{
        TextView name;
    }
}
```

The issue with Your implementation was in having own `ArrayList<LifeTask> data`. However it's not needed, because parent class `ArrayAdapter<LifeTask>` already has container for items.

And update the list using code like that:

```
adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll(negativeListData);
```

Methods [clear()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#clear%28%29) and [addAll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll%28T...%29) will call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).

Comment: Your reasoning is correct but your code is flawed. You're still using `this.context = context` although you've removed the local `context` field and also `convertView.getContext()` will throw an NPE as `convertView` is null.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that minor issues.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to call the `clear()` method.  It deletes everything in `positiveListData`

Comment: Ended up using something very similar to get my app to work.  Thanks!